# Fastest way to copy percentage of rows from massive table?

Tags: sql, performance, select, insert, teradata

I have a large table (db2.table1) containing a little over 3 billion rows of data. I'm trying to select a certain percentage (say 50 percent as an example) of rows from that very large table and insert it into another table that is initially empty.

I have this query

```
INSERT INTO db1.table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM db2.table1;
```

This works but, it is *incredibly* slow. It took nearly an hour just to select around 80% of the table. However when I run a select * and insert query copying over all rows of data (like below), it finishes within 3 minutes.

```
INSERT INTO db1.table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT * FROM db2.table1;
```

From my reasearch, I gather it has something to do with TOP needing to sort the rows of data first which requires a lot of disk I/O and this can cause quite a significant slowdown especially on a table as large as this.

So, I'm wondering now, what would be the *fastest* way to select and copy over some specified portion of data from one very large table into another? The rows selected doesn't necessarily need to be random or ordered in any way.

Edit: I should add that I don't really know or care what which rows are selected as the table contains randomly generated alphanumerical strings. I just need to copy over x rows or y % of the table for testing purposes.

Comment: Step 1 - determine which rows you want to copy.

Comment: Step 2 - Insert the `"wanted"` rows to a temp table.

Comment: What's your Teradata release? TOP resulting in a sort sounds like a very old one. Try a `SEELCT * FROM db2.table1 SAMPLE 0.5` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Export the table to a file, cut required amout and import the file.